# Netbeans VisualJSF (Woodstock) Design view not available in 6.7.1

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans6.7, woodstock

I recently installed netbeans 6.9, but VisualJSF Design view was not available in it. I Googled and it seems design view is not available after version 6.7.1. So I downloaded that version, but now I still dont have the design view.

Does anyone know how to enable design view, or is there any other option to design the UI like we do using design view?

Answer (score 1):

From here: http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic37586.html

> NetBeans 6.7.1 was the last version
>   with support for the visual  desinger.
>   Be aware that you will able to
>   visually work with JSF files,  not
>   plain JSP.

Maybe, Using Netbeans **6.9.1**, you could check the following out:

There is a plugin called '**Web Preview**' that will open the file in your external browser for a preview and allow you to immediately see the changes you make (after refreshing the browser).

But as far as I'm aware there isn't a WYSIWYG web page designer, and I can't seem to find one in the Plugins after a 'quick' search in Google.

Maybe you could look here for alternatives:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833/looking-for-wysiwyg-html-editor

Comment: See my answer on how to enable it. I am one of the remaining Woodstock committers, and provided detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable VisualJSF in NetBeans 6.7.1 by doing the following:

1. Go to **Tools** --> **Plugins**
2. Select the **Available Plugins** tab.
3. Choose `Visual JSF`, `Visual JSF Runtime`, and `Visual Web JSF Backwards Compatibility Kit`  from the plugins list.
4. Install the plugins.
5. Create a new project **Java Web** --> **Web Application** --> Choose **Visual Web JavaServerFaces** and a visual design time view will appear.

[image: New Visual JSF Project Creation Wizard]

[image: Visual JSF Design Time]

Answer (score -2):

Choose "java desktop application" from New Project menu, not java class.
Just guessing your problem, I'm not sure why you're not seeing it. I'm using 6.9 for a GUI.

Comment: i need java web project... so i chose that. I can see the code view, but not the design view

Comment: Are you creating applet or JSP/servlet scripts? If you are creating jsp or webserver based projects, write your html for gui or use an html editor.

Comment: Im creating a JSF page. ok, but i thought i would be nice if i had the design view which is handy to develop the GUI